# Android TextView Smart quotes

Tags: android, textview

I can't able to display left double quotes and right double quotes in Android. How to do that? eg: “What do you want Bec?” I am not talking about double quotation mark, eg:"

Comment: The term for these is "smart quotes".

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("&ldquo;What do you want Bec?&rdquo;"));
```

The quote marks you are looking for can be found here: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Comment: Yup, basically this. You may *possibly* run into some weird issues on different versions of android though. As I recall, older versions had poor support for some subset of unicode characters, but I'm not sure where these characters would fall.

Comment: Indeed, make sure to test it on older versions where I've personally experienced missing Unicode characters in the system fonts.

Comment: Those texts are dynamic from server. Atleast any solution to replace those left and right double quotes to normal double quotes? That will also solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying now, your original question has been answered.